# MissingPropertyException in groovysh

Tags: groovy, groovyshell

I run `groovysh`, and type the following code:

```
groovy:000> String s = "Hello"
===> Hello
groovy:000> s
ERROR groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException:
No such property: s for class: groovysh_evaluate
        at groovysh_evaluate.run (groovysh_evaluate:2)
        ...
groovy:000>
```

How to access the `s` here?

(If I change `String s = "Hello"` to `s = "Hello"`, I can access it. But I want to know how to access it in the example)

---

**UPDATE**

I want to use `String s = "Hello"` to define a variable because I want to declare the type of it. For example, if I write:

```
Date date = []
```

The date will be a `java.util.Date`. But if I write:

```
date = []
```

It will be a `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The expression `s = "Hello"` sets a shell variable, the expression `String s = "Hello"` sets a local variable which does not get saved to the shell's environment. Please see the [Groovy Shell documentation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Shell#GroovyShell-Variables) for more information. I am not quite sure what you are trying to achieve but you might rather want to go with [Groovy Console](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Console) to evaluate Groovy scripts.

Comment: thank you, **groovy console** can let me do it. You mean, there is no way to get the `s` from `String s = ...` in `groovysh`, right?

Comment: You could wrap it in a [function](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Shell#GroovyShell-Functions) and return `s` whenever you need it. That would be another option.

Answer (score 1):

simply set it to interpreterMode

`groovy:000> :set interpreterMode`

and you can just straightly use

`Date date = []`

ref: http://www.groovy-lang.org/groovysh.html#GroovyShell-InterpreterMode

Comment: TY.

This is what I expected as a Python user. now I execute always `groovysh --define=interpreterMode`

Answer (score 0):

You can write

```
date = [] as Date
```

to make sure date really has type Date. I had a similar problem and used

```
bin = [1, 26, 42 ,7] as byte[]
bin.encodeBase64()
```