# Closure error on groovysh

Tags: groovy, groovyshell

Run `groovysh` v2.3.6:

```
groovy:000> def f = {x -> x}
groovy:000> f(1)
```

```
ERROR groovy.lang.MissingMethodException:
No signature of method: groovysh_evaluate.f() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer) values: [1]
Possible solutions: is(java.lang.Object), run(), run(), find(), any(), any(groovy.lang.Closure)
```

Is this error a known bug for `closure` on `groovysh`?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130529/missingpropertyexception-in-groovysh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a known issue, using def in groovysh doesn't work like you'd expect. Variables declared with `def` or with a datatype don't get stored in the GroovyShell's binding, which is where the shell is looking for the names entered in the repl.

It will work if you declare the variable without def like this:

```
f = { x -> x }
```

Comment: Eliminating `def` keyword from named `closure` is actually more appreciated when `closure` is thought of an `expression`.