# Why groovyConsole supports `def name = "Neo"` while groovysh does not

Tags: groovy, groovyshell, groovy-console

Following is 2 lines of code:

```
def name = "Neo"
println name
```

If I execute it in `groovysh`, I will get `Unknown property: name` error.
If I execute it in `groovyConsole`, everything goes on well.

Comment: @dmahapatro: i think [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7130529/217324) is a better candidate for closing as a duplicate than that one (which also has the Set declaration issue going on). but i think the question is less 'why does groovysh do this' than 'why was groovysh designed that way'. which may not be answerable, this may just be quibbling over the close reason.

Comment: @NathanHughes one of the answer ( from @dmahapatro ) has comments about the reason why `groovysh` behaves as such. But you are correct the other question would be a better duplicate. However, this has been fixed in Groovy 2.4.0 as stated in the answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want features from Groovy 2.4.0 you can use

`:set interpreterMode true` to see a difference. :)

```
groovy:000> def a = 10
===> 10
groovy:000> a
Unknown property: a
groovy:000> :set interpreterMode true
groovy:000> a
Unknown property: a
groovy:000> def b = 100
===> 100
groovy:000> b
===> 100
groovy:000>
```

Comment: Slap this into your ~/.groovy/groovysh.rc file if you want to make it the default behavior.

Comment: @Apteryx Actually for me it sets seem to persist across sessions--although I hate to rely on that.