# Default parameter in closure

Tags: groovy, closures

Looking at the groovy  [manual](http://groovy-lang.org/closures.html#_normal_parameters), I see that I should be able to use default parameters in closures, like so:

```
def closureWithTwoArgAndDefaultValue = { int a, int b=2 -> a+b }
assert closureWithTwoArgAndDefaultValue(1) == 3
```

However, running that in `groovysh` gives me the following error:

> ERROR groovy.lang.MissingMethodException:
>   No signature of method: groovysh_evaluate.closureWithTwoArgAndDefaultValue() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer) values: [1]

Could somebody tell me why?

Comment: I have `Groovy Version: 2.4.7 JVM: 1.8.0_112 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Linux`, running on Arch Linux... Did you run that on `groovysh`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to omit `def`:

```
closureWithTwoArgAndDefaultValue = { int a, int b=2 -> a+b }
assert closureWithTwoArgAndDefaultValue(1) == 3
```

For further explanation, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130529/missingpropertyexception-in-groovysh).

Comment: Looks like Groovy shell thing, but I don't understand it completely? Your solution works in `groovysh`, but my issue is that I try to run that from a JenkinsFile, and there I get `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'closure' found among steps` with your solution... but it might be a problem with Jenkins only.

Comment: Seems like I have an issue related to jenkins, since I can run the version _with_ `def` in `groovyConsole`...

Comment: @JonesV, it's not `groovyConsole` but `groovysh`.

Comment: I mean, the version with `def` works in `groovyConsole` (as proposed in your link) but not in `groovysh`

Comment: Which is why I said that my problem looks more like an issue in Jenkins, after all ;)